# Revoke a requestAccessToEntityType: authorization on Mavericks so I can test my app

Tags: macos, cocoa, permissions, osx-mavericks, ekeventkit

I'm developing a CLI app that requests access to Reminders app on OSX Mavericks. Everything works fine with requesting permission, and detecting if the user has disabled the permission. The problem I have is that I cannot completely revoke the permission from the app in my OS. The app appears in Prefs -> Privacy -> Reminders, and the most I can do is disable the permission, but I want to (again) test if the permission request is fired correctly. Is there any way to completely remove the permission, as in remove the App from Prefs -> Privacy -> Reminders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the CLI command:

```
tccutil reset Reminders
```

(and `man tccutil` for details)

Comment: Very true! I found the answer later, but didn't come back to share it :(. Happy to help you build up your reputation! :D